# Why does Russia see NATO as an aggressor when the Istanbul document signed by Russia grants each participant the right to chose its allies separately?

Tags: russian-federation, international-relations, armed-conflict, international-law, nato

The [Istanbul document](https://www.osce.org/files/f/documents/6/5/39569.pdf) was a declaration signed in 1999 by Russia and Ukraine. Its legal character is similar to that of the Declaration of Human rights.

It contains the following paragraph:

> We reaffirm the inherent right
> of each and every participating State to be free to choose or change its security arrangements,
> including treaties of alliance, as they evolve.

So why is Russia complaining that countries of the former Soviet Union want to join NATO when it signed a declaration granting that right explicitly?

Comment: Comments deleted. Please remember that [comments are for improving the question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment), not for answering it or for debating its subject matter.

Answer (score 102):

Russia (the Russian government) **claims to believe** that Ukraine and Europe are not sovereign actors, but rather controlled by the US. I do not know if they actually **do believe** that, but considering their apparent mis-judgements to date that is not impossible.

Russia also **claims to believe** that "the West" (read: Washington) are actively fomenting [colour revolutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colour_revolution) in the ex-Soviet sphere to diminish Russian influence, and possibly in Russia itself to overthrow the current government.  Again, I cannot judge if they **do believe** it.

They claim that "the West" exploited a brief moment of Russian weakness to take away the empire which is historically Russia's birthright as the [successor of the Roman Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moscow,_third_Rome) and the representative of Christian civilization. Basically, blame the language of the OSCE document on that drunkard Yeltsin, who resigned that year. And if the populations in the [Russkiy Mir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_world) fail to see it the same way, that makes Russia claim those populations are misled by corrupted elites and need to be rescued.

Comment: Again, did Russia withdraw from that declaration or did they withdraw from the memorandum of Budapest which is of similar importance for the stability of that region.

Comment: While this answer offers good insight on the intent behind Russia's foreign policy in Europe, it fails to answer the actual question - what is the political difference between Russia, Ukraine and NATO on the *Istanbul declaration* that all are citing in their favour in support of their political stance? Due to the context it ignores, this answer is also flawed as it creates the impression that Russia is the party at fault ... it can be improved.

Comment: @sfxedit, I do not think that Russia cares one way or the other about the exact words they signed two decades ago. They see themselves in a struggle of systems with the West, and any current action or past declaration is seen through that lens. (The same applies to a lesser degree to the West, because the West does not see Russia as an existential threat unless they go for MAD.)

Comment: @o.m. Even if we go by your logic that Russia and the west no longer care about the agreements they sign, they still make it a point to bring up these agreements in their political bickering. And the questioner is asking what exactly are these public political claims and differences, with respect to the Istanbul declaration. Your answer would be factual and complete only if you include that too.

Comment: @sfxedit, you are reading an equality between the Russian and Western approach into propaganda into my answer which I explicitly did not make. I believe that **Russia** is the aggressor and lying to defend an unjustifiable crime.

Comment: @o.m. Russia is absolutely the aggressor. Nobody can dispute that. The US too was once an aggressor in a similar situation - Cuba wanted to align with Russia, and have a Russian nuclear base that would threaten US self-interest. Today Ukraine aligning with NATO and Svestapol, Crimea falling into NATO hands threatens Russian self-interest. I call it hypocritical to call one of these action as justified and the other as evil, when both are based on similar political motivations. The treaty referenced in this question also shows the political fears and desires of all, and is insightful for that.

Comment: @o.m. And if you genuinely believe Russia is lying, then please do add it to your answer and say so explicitly so that there is no confusion about it. That can certainly be one of the possible right answers, and I wouldn't have initiated this discussion ...

Comment: @sfxedit, twice before I had an edit in the window, only to cancel it. I belive the Russian government tells many lies, and that it tells many falsehoods which it may or may not believe. And if they do genuinely believe falsehoods they tell, it would not be lying. If Russia genuinely was in a war for survival instigated by the US, it would be justified to disregard agreements made before. I'm firmly convinced that the war was instigated by Russia, but the Russian leadership may have cut itself off from honest information. So they feel justified to make 'small lies' in this confrontation.

Comment: I appreciate that your answer stuck to the question. The tone suggests that you don't believe them, but rightly doesn't concern itself with *your* beliefs.

Comment: @o.m. Nobody will disagree with you if you say Russians are no saints. But this question doesn't support that (atleast from what you have written so far). The Istanbul declaration does support Russia's claim to be upset about Ukraine wanting to join NATO (article 8 and 9 are actually quite clear about that). If you are saying Russia is lying about the Istanbul declaration, you should add more info / background to support that argument than the blanket (and vague) argument that *"it's just their personality"* or "drunk Yeltsin".

Answer (score 21):

Circumstances can change, perceptions can change, and people can change their minds.

Once upon a time in the 1990s *Russia itself* wanted to join NATO.

But through a series of smaller geopolitical conflicts and perceived political slights, Russia has come to believe that Cold War conflicts with the US have not been extinguished.

With Ukraine, their perception seems to be that US meddling has finally arrived on their doorstep and that their interests are to pre-empt any further deterioration.

So the reason Russia is complaining now about the alliances of its neighbours, despite having previously indicated a willingness to accept independent arrangements, is that those governing Russia have changed their mind about the effects and implications since they last indicated their acceptance.

As others have already indicated in answers and comments, the Russian population also largely repudiates the politics of the 1990s, so that decisions made then could not be expected to reflect political views now.

Comment: But why didn't Russia withdraw from the declaration of Istanbul?

Comment: Because they have no problem simply ignoring it.

Comment: @CuriousIndeed The Istanbul document doesn’t really have any teeth, at least not against a state fond of brinkmanship politics like Russia, so there is no downside to them choosing to simply act like it never existed. In contrast, Russia actively choosing to pull out would look bad both internationally _and_ domestically, which would be problematic for the current regime.

Comment: @CuriousIndeed: at 200+ pages, one can find whatever they want in there to support their own position. Case in point, as note under the Q, Russia [invoked](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-cites-1999-charter-text-insistence-indivisible-security-2022-02-01/) "indivisible security" from that doc to justify their [implied] threat of invasion (at the beginning of Feb 2022).

Comment: @Fizz. No..Let's see try to prove from that document that Russia needs to have full control over South America by 2024. Sure by redefining words you can justify anything. Indivisible security means that the security of one state in that region is linked to the security of another state. This war could have been prevented similar to the Cuban missile crisis which was arguably closer to a escalation between two great powers...

Comment: "...the Russian population also largely repudiates the politics of the 1990s..." I think this is mostly focused on economic developments in the 1990s, but is it also related to foreign relations. The Russian population really wants to invade Ukraine? I don't know. Maybe not all of them.

Comment: @Trilarion, the question might not be "do they want to invade Ukraine?", but "do they want to confront the West?". When the Nazis got to gates of Moscow, they didn't say "do you want to invade Poland?", they said "do you want to confront the Nazis?". My point is that they may have ambiguous feelings about Ukrainian separatism in its own right, but not when Ukrainian separatists are a tentacle of the West.

Comment: @Austin Hemmelgarn "Russia actively choosing to pull out would look bad both internationally and domestically" Why should it look bad domestically?

Comment: @convert it means Putin murdered a stupid amount of Russia's population for absolutely nothing

Comment: @user253751 I understood that pull out was refering to the Istanbul document.

Comment: Not a fan of this answer because "Russia" is a country, not a person. Countries don't have beliefs. They have governments, which have foreign policies. Those are run by human beings who have beliefs (and agendas). But of course each human maintains their own personal set of those. Anthropomorphizing an entire nation is forgivable in a question, but answers shouldn't engage in it.

Comment: @T.E.D., I agree with your points, but I don't think there is much confusion in the context that we are talking foremost about the mindset of the Russian administration, and to at least some degree the Russian population - rather than a hypothetical nation state with its own mind or body.

Comment: For a tangible example of the issue, your second paragraph kind of implies there was some popular desire in the country to join NATO, when in fact there's no evidence it was anything more than a [temporary whim of Putin's](https://www.trtworld.com/magazine/russia-could-have-joined-nato-but-why-didn-t-they-do-it-55561). I'm also unconvinced that his reasons for that particular bit of angling have been deeply studied or understood.

Comment: The linked article seems to argue as though he's since been acting like a spiteful spurned teen, but given the other things he was engaged in at that time, I'm unconvinced he wasn't just hoping to get interior leverage to render the body as impotent as the UN Security Council. There are probably some other possible rationales I haven't thought of, and I don't know that anyone's gathered enough info on the subject to even make educated guesses with.

Comment: @T.E.D., your own linked article says Gorbachev and Yeltsin also desired NATO membership.

Answer (score 15):

The extent that Russia accepted that principle had already reached its limit by 2008, when (in the context of the 2008 NATO summit in Bucharest, which he attended), where the candidacy of Georgia and Ukraine were on the table,  Putin [said](http://www.en.kremlin.ru/events/president/transcripts/24903) that

> We view the appearance of a powerful military bloc on our borders, a bloc whose members are subject in part to Article 5 of the Washington Treaty, as a direct threat to the security of our country. The claim that this process is not directed against Russia will not suffice. [...]
>
> We have eliminated bases in Cam Ranh (Vietnam) and in Cuba. We have withdrawn our troops deployed in eastern Europe, and withdrawn almost all large and heavy weapons from the European part of Russia. And what happened? A [US] base in Romania, where we are now, one in Bulgaria, an American missile defence area in Poland and the Czech Republic. That all means moving military infrastructure to our borders.

(TBH, I'm [not sure](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/79512/what-did-putin-mean-by-we-have-withdrawn-almost-all-large-and-heavy-weapo) what he meant by "we have [...] withdrawn almost all large and heavy weapons from the European part of Russia".) In the same speech he says that NATO's "out of area" operations (like Kosovo) cast doubt on the alliance's true goals, and complains that the (then recently admitted to NATO) Latvia didn't give citizenship to its Russian speakers.

And while this was surely not first time someone in a position of power in Russia said something like that (even Yeltsin protested the idea of a NATO expansion in the 1990s, but was more easily [placated](https://declassifieduk.org/revealed-boris-yeltsin-privately-supported-nato-expansion-in-1990s/)), Russia made its point in 2008 by invading Georgia, in response to the renewed clashes between Georgian armed forces and South Ossetian separatists. Later on, Medvedev (president during the seat swap with Putin) [declared](https://www.reuters.com/article/idINIndia-60645720111121) that the armed intervention in Georgia was essential in having prevented Georgia from joining NATO.

Some Western observers [pointed out](https://foreignpolicy.com/2022/02/22/russia-ukraine-invasion-georgia-2008-south-ossetia-tskhinvali/) in Feb 2022 that Russia was repeating the "Georgia playbook" with Ukraine.

Yeah, someone is gonna say "but Finland, 2023". Russia would have perhaps prevented that too, if their forces were not overstretched in Ukraine. [For now](https://www.voanews.com/a/finland-joins-nato-dealing-major-blow-to-russia/7035429.html) they've declared that Northern Europe has become "unstable":

> Russia's Foreign Ministry said Moscow "will be forced to take military-technical and other retaliatory measures to counter the threats to our national security arising from Finland’s accession to NATO.”
>
> It said Finland's move marks "a fundamental change in the situation in Northern Europe, which had previously been one of the most stable regions in the world.”

In a 2022 [speech](http://en.kremlin.ru/events/president/news/68606), referencing Peter the Great's campaigns (against Sweden, but also around Narva, presently in Estonia) Putin said that (similarly) "it fell to our lot to return and reinforce as well" places where "from time immemorial, the Slavs lived". Anyhow, as of 2022, Putin [was](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2022/jun/29/russia-condemns-nato-invitation-finland-sweden) drawing a finer line between NATO candidates that Russia had  territorial disputes with and those without:

> “We don’t have problems with Sweden and Finland like we do with Ukraine,” the Russian president told a news conference in the Turkmenistan capital of Ashgabat. “We don’t have territorial differences.”

For the latter, in late 2021, Russia [demanded](https://www.bnnbloomberg.ca/russia-demands-nato-return-to-1997-in-security-treaty-proposals-1.1697377) a return to pre-1997 armed forces deployments in Europe, so that NATO's expansion since then would be, more or less, confined to paper.

---

BTW, although the Q itself notes this to some extent, I should probably mention here that many European countries [regard](https://ifsh.de/file-CORE/documents/yearbook/english/95_96/Fastenrath.pdf) the CSCE/OSCE conference outputs as politically but not legally binding. Among the numerous principles declared in  OSCE documents, Russia for instance likes and insists on the "indivisible security" one. In particular they [raised it](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-cites-1999-charter-text-insistence-indivisible-security-2022-02-01/) again in Feb 2022, shortly before invading Ukraine. And after the Georgia war, Medvedev proposed a European Security Treaty that would have raised the "indivisible security" principle to a legally binding status, but this was rejected by other countries, [including](https://www.jstor.org/stable/resrep18640) Germany, who argued that it is too vague for such a role, and in fact (despite being in the same Istanbul declaration) rather contradictory with the freedom of countries to choose alliances:

> German Minister of State Werner Hoyer noted the difficulties involved in attempting to make the principle of indivisible security into a mandatory legal requirement. “How, for example, does the concept of indivisible security fit with the freedom of countries to choose what alliances they belong to, something to which we are all committed?” he asked.

As noted by other analysts (in that paper), the 2009 Russian treaty draft in fact proposed to resolve this by making any other prior commitments *subordinate* to this "indivisible security" principle (via its Article 9), so essentially giving Russia, from then on, a legal veto over NATO expansion, troop deployments, etc., assuming NATO members would have signed on. Even the right to collective self-defense was made subordinate to the same "indivisible security" in this proposal. In case of being attacked, a signatory state retained the right to convene an Extraordinary Conference, where collective defense decisions had to be unanimous (minus the attacking country, if among the signatories). Needless to say that such a design favored big countries over small ones since the former could self-defend on their own, an action which did not need Conference approval.

The 1999 Istanbul joint ministerial statement even contained some rather more concrete commitments like (p. 50)

> 19. [...] We welcome the commitment by the Russian Federation to complete withdrawal of the Russian forces from the territory of Moldova by the end of 2002.

Which, of course, has yet to happen even 20 years later, and was a bone of contention in some later OSCE summits e.g. [in 2010](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-osce-summit-idUSTRE6B16ZQ20101203).

Comment: In short, they do not feel bound by the papers they subscribed back then.

Comment: @PhilipKlöcking: yes, but in fairness most European countries [consider](https://ifsh.de/file-CORE/documents/yearbook/english/95_96/Fastenrath.pdf) CSCE/OSCE documents to be not legally binding too. In fact, when Russia tried in 2009 to draft a new European Security Treaty based on some of those [vague] principles they liked (in particular "indivisible security") they received immediate pushback including from Germany ([arguing](https://www.jstor.org/stable/resrep18640) that "indivisible security" is too vague for a treaty.)

Answer (score 7):

Others have answered this question more broadly, ignoring the context you asked it in - namely, the *Istanbul document*, which was a result of the [Istanbul summit](https://www.osce.org/event/summit_1999).

Just as you have focused on one relevant clause of importance to you in the document (i.e. article 8 that talks about security alliances) there does seem to be a **political misunderstanding** between all the parties involved on what *they* consider to be the most relevant / important part / clauses of the document.

For Russia, with reference to the Russia-Ukraine conflict, the most important part (emphasised) are in **article 8 and 9**:

> 8. Each participating State has an equal right to security. We reaffirm the inherent right of each and every participating State to be free to choose or change its security arrangements, including treaties of alliance, as they evolve. Each State also has the right to neutrality. Each participating State will respect the rights of all others in these regards. **They will not strengthen their security at the expense of the security of other States.** Within the OSCE no State, group of States or organization can have any pre-eminent responsibility for maintaining peace and stability in the OSCE area or can consider any part of the OSCE area as its sphere of influence.
> 9. We will build our relations in conformity with the concept of common and comprehensive security, guided by equal partnership, solidarity and transparency. **The security of each participating State is inseparably linked to that of all others.** We will address the human, economic, political and military dimensions of security as an integral whole.
>
> *Art. 8,9, Charter for European Security in 1999 OSCE Istanbul Document p.3*

This is also what Russian Foreign Minister Sergei Lavrov told the US:

> Lavrov told reporters that Russia's stance was based on a 1999 charter signed in Istanbul by members of the Organisation for Security and Cooperation in Europe, which includes the United States and Canada.
>
> The charter says countries should be free to choose their own security arrangements and alliances, but goes on to say that they "will not strengthen their security at the expense of the security of other states".
>
> ... *"Our western colleagues are simply trying not even to ignore but to consign to oblivion this key principle of international law agreed in the Euro-Atlantic space,"* Lavrov told reporters. - *[Russia cites 1999 charter text for insistence on 'indivisible security'](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/russia-cites-1999-charter-text-insistence-indivisible-security-2022-02-01/) (Feb 2022)*.

So it appears that the political misunderstanding here is that Ukraine is giving importance to the clause about joining alliances, Russia was giving primacy to the clause that such alliances need to consider the security concerns of others while the Anglosphere / NATO focused more on the part that OSCE countries cannot create or claim a "sphere of influence" (which it believed Russia was doing with Eastern Europeon countries).

*(I'll leave it to the readers, and historians, to decide if this political misunderstanding is a deliberate farce or an unintentional tragedy)*.

Comment: I am under impression that Russia is now "strengthening the own security" at the expense of some "other states", notably Ukraine.

Comment: @Stančikas Russia's claim is that they had no choice because Ukraine wasn't willing to engage with Russia to address their security concerns if Ukraine joining NATO. (And note that Russia doesn't see this as a Russia - Ukraine issue but a Anglosphere led NATO-Russia issue. From their perspective, if anyone in NATO had assured Russia that Ukraine wouldn't be admitted to NATO, keeping in mind Russia's (in)security concerns, matters wouldn't have escalated this far.)

Comment: @sfxedit isn't it conjecture that Russia wouldn't have invaded had NATO promised not to help Ukraine if they were invaded? I get that that claim was made, but a lot of claims get made that aren't true.

Comment: @bharring No. Short answer - for Russia it is all about Svestapol, Crimea, which Ukraine was leasing to Russia. Ukraine's threat to not only to end the lease but also join NATO is the root cause of the war, as it threatens Russia's military and economic security. (The comment limits me from typing a long answer; if you'd like to know more please make a new question here on why Russia considers Crimea to be so important and existential to its survival as a nation.)

Comment: I can't find a clear definition of "threat" in the Document, but Russia is bending it to be meaningless. If Ukraine deciding to end a lease of its own sovereign territory, or joining a defensive alliance, is a threat; what isn't a threat? What if Ukraine changed the price of grain? Threat to their food security! The Document also appears to lack an enforcement clause (the death of so many peace agreements), merely "encouraging" them to use the The Court of Conciliation and Arbitration (Russia signed but never ratified), but unilateral decision and enforcement by invasion was not the intent.

Comment: @Schwern *If Ukraine deciding to end a lease of its own sovereign territory ... is a threat; what isn't a threat?* The US didn't allow sovereign Cuba to have a Russian nuclear base on Cuba and used its military might to prevent it, right? It's the same case here too. (And if you read the political history of Crimea, it shows Russia always had better claim on it than Ukraine.)

Comment: @sfxedit Yes, the USA was an aggressor against Cuba. Now what does this have to do with Ukraine?

Comment: @sfxedit In the Cuban Missile Crisis there was no treaty like we're discussing, Cuba was willing to accept the missiles, the missiles strengthened Cuban and Russian security at the expense of the US (a 3rd party), and the US never fired a shot. In our Sevastopol hypothetical there is a treaty, Ukraine is unwilling, losing access to Sevastopol is not an existential threat to Russia, and Russia invaded. *"And if you read the political history of Crimea, it shows Russia always had better claim on it than Ukraine."* This is [irredentism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_irredentism).

Comment: @user253751 Ukraine wanting to join NATO and Cuba wanting to host a Russian nuclear base are both well within the rights of each country's sovereignty. So what makes US attacking Cuba, and Russia attacking Ukraine different? US didn't like Cuban leadership. Russia doesn't like Ukrainian leadership. US felt threaten. Russia feels threatens. Cuba suffers. Ukraine suffers. The common element villains for Cuba were the US and USSR / Russia. The common villains for Ukraine's suffering too are the US and Russia.

Comment: @Schwern *losing access to Sevastopol is not an existential threat to Russia* - it is as it affects the Russians both militarily and economically. (And treaties applies both ways - Ukrainian politicians are not as naive and innocent as the west likes to portray them, and they too have violated the terms of the treaties while pretending otherwise). And no, Russia always had better claim on Crimea as it came into Ukraine's possession by a political sleight of administrative redrawing of the boundaries. Even Ukraine knew that leasing it to Russia was the only way to possess it.

Comment: @sfxedit "Existential threat" means it is a threat to one's existence. Having nukes based 100 miles away from your coastline? That's a threat to existence. Losing a nice port on the Black Sea because your neighbor doesn't want to lease it to you anymore? That's an inconvenience. Russia wouldn't even be cut off from the Black Sea, they have other ports.

Comment: @Schwern It's the only warm water port that Russia has and hence is very important to the Russian Navy for a host of reasons - if you'd like to know more please make a new question here on why Russia considers Crimea to be so important and existential to its survival as a nation. Comments are limiting and we'll be derailing into a totally new discussion ...

Answer (score 5):

To answer the part about "Why does Russia see NATO as an aggressor", we must go back to the same year 1999. In 1999, at least according to Russian point of view, NATO attacked Yugoslavia. Then there were Afghanistan, Iraq and Libya. All of these actions are seen by Russia, and countries outside the Western world, as NATO aggression.

As mentioned in some other answer, 1999 Yeltsin was president. He and the majority of his government were relative pro Western, which explains why they signed this document.

Comment: as I understand it, the NATO attack on Yugoslavia was approved by the UN, and it could have been done by any military force, but the NATO force was most nearby which is why they did it.

Comment: @user253751 Defenetly not approved by the UN.

Comment: oh, the UN approved a different one - a very similar one. Considering that the only reason the UN didn't approve this one was that bad countries wanted to be allowed to do Nazi stuff, it seems like it was morally justified.

Comment: "Why'd you punch me?! I didn't do anything to you." "Because those people over there punched some bad people 20 years ago and we don't think they should be punching anyone without our say so." "So why'd you punch ME?!" "Because you might join those people." "Yeah, because you keep PUNCHING ME!"

Comment: @Schwern What this was exactly refering to?

Comment: @convert The Russian logic that because NATO did some "invading" they didn't like, they get to invade Ukraine, a non-NATO member. As if it's Russia's turn now.

Comment: @Schwern Sure you can see it this way, but as mentioned NATO did some invading, even you used quotes, this is a valide reason to call NATO aggressor.

Answer (score 3):

Russia does not recognise the sovereignty of the other Soviet republics, considers them all "historically part of Russia", and ESPECIALLY Belarus and Ukraine are considered such, as well as the Baltic states.

It's basically the same ploy that China uses to claim ownership of Taiwan, parts of Japan, the Philippines, and other countries.

Russia is also extremely paranoid about any of their neighbours, and considers any neighbour who is not under their complete control to be an enemy by definition. As NATO was set up explicitly to curb Soviet/Russian aggression it's Moscow's main boogeyman so any country daring to want to join NATO (or even have friendly relations with them) is considered a major threat.

This is reflected in repeated Russian demands that the Baltic states and all former Warsaw Pact nations leave NATO and completely demilitarise, which not only removes them as a potential threat but obviously also leaves them open for invasion and inclusion into Russia proper.

Comment: "Russia does not..." I often wish there would be some suitable citations for such claims. How do we know that Russia does this?

Comment: "Russian demands that the Baltic states and all former Warsaw Pact nations leave NATO" When did Russia made this demand?

Comment: Russia did make that claim in January 2022 before the war.

Comment: @alamar And thats an other misunderstanding, Russia has demanded that NATO troops and bases will be removed from that countries, while NATO in this context stands for USA. The countries still can stay NATO members including article 5.

Comment: @convert that would make article 5 untenable. Russia quickly invading weakly defended territory and then immediately threatening use of nuclear weapons if contested, **as we have already seen in Ukraine**.

Comment: @Edheldil No, it wouldn't because Russia invading *any* NATO country would mean Russia would be at war with *all* NATO countries. And if NATO didn't come to the defence of a member state, and doesn't retaliate, the NATO alliance will itself collapse.

Comment: @sfxedit all NATO countries which would have sacrificed their ability to defend themselves as part of that deal

Comment: @convert no, Russia demanded those countries leave NATO and become non-aligned, AND completely disarm, AND kick out any NATO troops on their soil. Which would leave them utterly defenceless against Russian aggression, which was of course the point of the demand.

Comment: @jwenting https://www.dw.com/en/russia-demands-nato-leave-eastern-europe-limit-missile-deployment/a-60173879 That Western sorce has liste Russian demands.

Answer (score 2):

One option is that Russia sees NATO's acceptance of those countries' membership as irresponsible, even as it does not deny these countries' right to participate. In the triangle of Russia, Eastern European countries and NATO, Russia sees the latter as the main culprit.

The question itself is misguided in the sense that Ukraine is not a part of NATO and is not being accepted to NATO in forseeable future. So even if Russia considers NATO an aggressor for something, it's definitely not for accepting Ukraine into NATO.

Answer (score 2):

You've confused two separate issues.

NATO expansion into Eastern Europe shows NATO is *untrustworthy*, not that it is aggressive. This is not inconsistent with the Istanbul document you cited, since that only says countries are free to apply. It does not say countries have to be accepted (note NATO denied membership to Russia itself). Since NATO [promised not to expand](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43781/did-nato-promise-gorbachev-not-to-accept-membership-applications-from-former-war), and then didn't deny membership, it shows NATO cannot be trusted.

NATO is an *aggressor* because it (or its ideological leaders) attacked Libya, Serbia, Afghanistan, Iraq, etc.

Comment: See this question for a discussion if NATO ever started a war https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/68436/has-nato-ever-started-a-war

Comment: +1 Indeed, I think the question is built on the ambiguous meaning of word *aggression*. E.g., Russia may refer to NATO expansion as *aggressive*, it does not mean that NATO has literally/legally engaged in a *military aggression* against Russia. On even more ambiguous use of the term one could cite Obama, who promised to *aggressively seek a lasting peace between Israel and the Palestinians* - here *aggressively* has clearly non-aggressive meaning.

Comment: Didn't NATO attack on UN's behalf to stop the fighting/ethnic cleansing/killing on civilians? They did not attack with a view to take over, permanently occupying a region unlike some other countries that wanted full lasting ownership.

Comment: No, NATO intervention in Serbia was not authorized by UN.

Comment: @stackoverblown First one was authorized by UN. Second one was not authorized - but the only reason it was not authorized, was that China and Russia wanted to do ethnic cleansings and not be attacked, so they needed to set precedent.